# Visual Studio 2013: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2013

I migrated some "native" c++ projects from Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 to Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1.  Rebuilding gave me this error.  I realized I did not have the Windows SDK installed, so I installed that next, but I'm still getting the error.  Anyone else get this on otherwise-clean VS project migrations?

Comment: You need to install the Windows SDK

Comment: Yep Damian you are correct.  But installing it after migrating the project doesn't fix the project.  See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I searched under the SDK folder for the missing file and found it.  Because the SDK was installed after I migrated the projects, the paths were not included in my projects.  I was able to fix everything by adding to my include and lib paths.

I added the following folders to my include paths:

> $(WindowsSdkDir)include\um
>
> $(WindowsSdkDir)include\shared

My full include path for both Debug and Release now looks like this:

> $(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include\um;$(WindowsSdkDir)include\shared;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;

I added the following folder to my lib paths (note that is specific to a 32-bit build! see x64 for 64-bit, and arm for arm builds...):

> $(WindowsSdkDir)lib\winv6.3\um\x86

My full lib path looks like this:

> $(WindowsSdkDir)lib;$(WindowsSdkDir)lib\winv6.3\um\x86;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\lib;$(VCInstallDir)lib;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib

Note that if you have a copy of the original project file, you can also fix the problem by re-migrating it again after the Windows SDK is installed.

Answer (score 6):

include path: `$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);`

lib paths:`$(VC_LibraryPath_x86);$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86);`